# Como hacer un switch en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo varios `if-else` que necesito simplificar:

```
var color = "";
if (tipo == "0") {
   color = "FF0000";
 } else if (tipo == "1") {
   color = "CC9900";
 } else if (tipo == "2") {
   color = "AA0000";
 .... 
 } else {
   color = "000000";
 }
```

Hay manera de hacer un `switch` en `javascript`?

Comment: La expresión `(tipo = "1")` es una asignación, no una comparación. Para comparar puedes usar `==` pero es más recomendado `===`.

Comment: @devconcept gracias, corregido

Comment: El [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch) usa internamente *igualdad estricta* (`===`) por lo que el código de tu pregunta y tu solución no son 100% equivalentes.

Comment: a lo que se refiere el buen @devconcept es a esto mi estimado Jordi http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: Revisa la referencia de la [instrucción switch de javascript de W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

También se puede utilizar la función corta de un `switch case` de la siguiente manera:

```js
var color = "";
var miTipo = prompt("Ingrese un numero");
var casos = {
    0: "#FF0000",
    1: "#CC9900",
    2: "#AA0000"    
};
//si hay condicion cumplida
if (casos[miTipo]) {  
  color = casos[miTipo];
}else{
  //Aqui lo que seria el default de un switch case tradicional
  color = "#000000";
}
alert('El color es: ' + color);
```

Comment: muy bueno y bonito!

Comment: Creo que deberías usar un arreglo en lugar de un objeto, te ahorra la necesidad de especificar las llaves como números. `var casos = ["#FF0000", ...]` es mucho más sencillo que como lo tienes ahora y funciona de la misma forma. Si las llaves fueran de otro tipo está justificado el uso del objeto.

Comment: gracias hermano :D

Answer (score 2):

Para ello puedes usar un `switch`, aunque dependiendo de donde venga la variable a identificar deberás trimearla o convertir el `String` en `int` primero o para que no de problemas:

```
var color = "";
var typeInt = parseInt(type)
alert(typeInt);
switch(typeInt) {
    case 0:
        color = "#FF0000"
        break;
    case 1:
        color = "#CC9900"
        break;
    case 2:
        color = "#AA0000"
        break;
    default:
        color = "#000000"
}
```

Comment: Los `switch` funcionan con strings también, no hay necesidad de convertir. `parseInt` debe usarse siempre `parseInt(variable, radix)`, o sea `parseInt(type, 10)`

Answer (score 2):

Un [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch) es básicamente una simplificación de una comparación estricta `===` en javascript con algunos valores añadidos.

Tomando como partida la siguiente comparación

```
if (variable === valor1) {
    // bloque 1 de código
} else if (variable === valor2) {
    // bloque 2 de código
} else if (variable === valor3) {
    // bloque 3 de código
} else {
   // bloque de código si las demás condiciones no se cumplen
}
```

Se traduce en

```
switch(variable) {
    case valor1:
        // bloque 1 de código
        break;
    case valor2:
        // bloque 2 de código
        break;
    case valor3:
        // bloque 3 de código
        break;
    default:
        // bloque de código si las demás condiciones no se cumplen
}
```

Recuerda que comparación relajada `==` y comparación estricta `===` no se [comportan igual](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Comparison_Operators) todo el tiempo por lo que no debes usar `switch` si tu código depende de alguna conversión de datos (o debes convertir antes de ejecutar el `switch`) ya que este **siempre** usará comparación estricta.

Cuales son los valores añadidos que se pueden obtener con un `switch` que pueden ser más complicados de obtener usando `if`?

1. Con el `switch` se puede ejecutar más de un bloque a la vez dependiendo de la condición. Para esto solo hay que quitar la instrucción `break` y esta continuará a los siguientes bloques de código

   ```
   switch(variable) {
       case valor1:
           // bloque 1 de código
       case valor2:
           // bloque 2 de código
           break;
       case valor3:
           // bloque 3 de código
           break;
       default:
           // bloque de código si las demás condiciones no se cumplen
   }
   ```

   En este caso si la `variable` es igual a `valor1` se ejecutarán tanto el código en el bloque 1 como en el bloque 2. Esto en algunas ocasiones puede ayudar a simplificar código. Esto es lo que se conoce como *código común* o *caída*. (Ten mucho cuidado con esto ya que este truco vuelve el código menos legible).
2. Debido a que `switch` usa comparación estricta se puede usar para simplificar código cuando se quiere hacer una comprobación de identidad.

   > Dos objetos distintos nunca son iguales tanto en la comparación estricta como relajada.
   >
   > Una expresión comparando objetos es `true` sólo si los operandos referencian exactamente el mismo objeto.

   Considera el siguiente caso

   ```js
   function fn() {
     // Bloque de código
   }

   var arr = [1, 2, 3];

   var foo = {};

   var obj = {
     prop: fn
   }

   switch (obj.prop) {
     case foo:
       console.log('Es el objeto foo');
       break;
     case fn:
       console.log('Es la funcion fn');
       break;
     case arr:
       console.log('Es el arreglo arr');
       break;
     default:
       console.log('No se lo que es');
   }
   ```

   El `switch` **funciona** con cualquier tipo de referencia, incluso funciones. Si mantienes una referencia a varios objetos que quieras identificar es muy sencillo usar un `switch` para saber de cual de ellos se trata ya que en javascript un objeto sólo es igual a si mismo (un objeto no es lo mismo que un [primitivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Primitivo)).

Para convertir tu código a switch

```js
var color = "";
var tipo = prompt("Ingrese un numero");

switch (tipo) {
  case "0":
    color = "FF0000";
    break;
  case "1":
    color = "CC9900";
    break;
  case "2":
    color = "AA0000";
    break;
  default:
    color = "000000";
}
alert('El color es: ' + color);
```

Answer (score -1):

Según la [referencia](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) de la instrucción `switch` de W3Schools, puedes adaptar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
var color = "";

switch (color) {
    case "0":
        color = "FF0000";
        break;
    case "1":
        color = "CC9900";
        break;
    case "2":
        color = "AA0000";
        break;
    default:
        // Establece algún valor por defecto 
        // "en caso de que ninguna condición aplique a las opciones anteriores".
        color = "000000";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no w3schools, mucho mejor MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Oh...ahora comprendo el voto negativo; pero dejaré la referencia que puse en mi respuesta _o si alguien mas desea editarla_; porque pienso que  la pregunta "tal como está" se soluciona con una simple búsqueda en Google :)

Comment: El voto negativo no fui yo, por si acaso ;)

Comment: @Shaz, ok no hay problema "de ahora en adelante, intentaré consultar otras fuentes de información como la citada en tu comentario" :)

Comment: Si la persona que responde ha verificado que el enlace de W3Schools contiene información correcta, ¿por qué no ponerlo? Descartar un enlace de W3Schools sólo porque es W3Schools no tiene sentido.

Comment: Para ti no tiene sentido, para mí sí, tuve muchos problemas en el pasado por referencias incorrectas de dicha página, y conozco casos similares, en efecto puede que hayan corregido muchos (o todos) los errores, pero en mi opinión sigue siendo "malo" el sitio web, además para probar que contiene información correcta, tal vez se haría comparando con otras fuentes, las cuales en ese caso sería mejor utilizar y seguir ;)